# Sending '__autoreleasing .....'to parameter of incompatible type

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

I have a block;

```
typedef void (^SIResponseHandler) (id obj, NSString *error);
```

and a method:

```
+ (void)uploadPhoto:(UIImage *)photo
toPathForComponents:(NSArray *)components
  completionHandler:(SIResponseHandler)responseHandler;
```

and another method which calls the above method:

```
+ (void)updateProfilePhoto:(UIImage *)photo handler:(SIResponseHandler *)handler {

    NSArray *components = @[@"users", sharedInstance.username, @"profile", @"photo", @"upload"];
    [SIRequest uploadPhoto:photo
       toPathForComponents:components
           progressHandler:nil
         completionHandler:handler];
}
```

In the last line, I get this error:

```
Sending '__autoreleasing SIResponseHandler *' (aka 'void (^__autoreleasing *)(__strong id, NSString *__strong)') to parameter of incompatible type 'SIResponseHandler' (aka 'void (^)(__strong id, NSString *__strong)')
```

I have no idea what this means. Can someone please explain what's going on ?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that `SIResponseHandler` is a block type, and as such should not be suffixed as a pointer with `*` in an argument list, unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: ahhh, wow, that was a mistake/typo. Thanks for pointing that out!